# Features for relationship between medical concepts in clinical texts

Tags: natural-language, feature-engineering

I was going through the paper: [Automatic extraction of relations between medical concepts in clinical texts by Roberts et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3168312/)

In the section: **Context Features**, it mentions set of 14 features.
In several of these, authors mention "**Any**" word,POS etc in the words between two concepts.

I am wondering how is "any" chosen? Is it that randomly a word is chosen between the concepts say when they choose feature **CF1**.

e.g. The patient was treated initially with [ceftriaxone]TREATMENT and [azithromycin]TREATMENT based on his history of [MRSA]PROBLEM.

In this example provided in the paper as **S1**, for the relation between azithromycin and MRSA would they choose any of the words in between from "based on his history of" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CF1 is a feature whose value is a vector where each element corresponds to one unique word. If the word is present between the two concepts of interest, then its corresponding value in the vector is 1, and 0 otherwise. As mentioned in the paper, the feature vector is sparse, i.e. most values are 0.

Note that the current state-of-the-art systems for relation extraction and classification typically use neural networks ([example 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01523)), not SVM.

Comment: With less than 400 clinical reports(discharge summary) in [i2b2 2010 dataset](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3168320/), will deep learning methods like the one mentioned in your paper be suitable for this dataset?

Comment: @KaushikAcharya That depends on a few things e.g. how many relations there are in total, how difficult it is to classify relations, etc., but that sounds reasonable to try. Also, CNN isn't deep :-)